# How can I reshape my wide data into a time series/long format?

Tags: python, dataframe, date

See the following data snippet:

[image]

The column from the right is a data variable ranging from August 2001 to August '97
What I would like to do is merge all these columns together into one 'Date' column. For further context, the columns are of equal length.

Comment: Could you expand on what it is you want to do, in merging the columns do you just want to keep the number inside the column or do you need to keep the date as well. If you don't need the date then you could sum together the date columns under a new column called date

Comment: This is the tricky part. I want to match the numbers under the date with the Material (i.e. ID). In other words, a structure that shows the number of purchases for "Material" in the respective month. I.e. time series...

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the dates, how much was purchased and the id of the material you could drop the columns that aren't dates (i.e. Del. time- Total) and transpose your dataset.

In pandas

```python
dataframe = dataframe.T
```